# Error passing data between view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I am trying to pass data from one view controller to another in Swift.

View Controller 1:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let selectedFiName = self.fetchedFiName[indexPath.row].fiName
    let selectedOneYear = self.fetchedFiName[indexPath.row].oneYear
    let selectedTwoYear = self.fetchedFiName[indexPath.row].twoYear
    let selectedThreeYear = self.fetchedFiName[indexPath.row].threeYear
    let selectedFourYear = self.fetchedFiName[indexPath.row].fourYear
    let selectedFiveYear = self.fetchedFiName[indexPath.row].fiveYear

    passData = [SecondTable(passedFIName: selectedFiName, passedOneYear: selectedOneYear, passedTwoYear: selectedTwoYear, passedThreeYear: selectedThreeYear, passedFourYear: selectedFourYear, passedFiveYear: selectedFiveYear)]


    performSegue(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController", sender: self)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if let selectedFiName = sender as!  ,
    let destVC = segue.destination as? SecondViewController {
        destVC.fiName = selectedFiName
    }
}
```

The error shows in "prepare for segue" in view controller 2 (receieving):

```
struct SecondTable {

    var passedFIName: String = ""
    var passedOneYear: String = ""
    var passedTwoYear: String = ""
    var passedThreeYear: String = ""
    var passedFourYear: String = ""
    var passedFiveYear: String = ""

}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var fiName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var sometext: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let fiDetails = SecondTable()

        fiName.text = SecondTable.passedFIName
        sometext.text = "Some Text"
```

Answer (score 0):

This bit:

```
if let selectedFiName = sender as!  ,
```

Should not even compile.

You need a type, like

```
if let selectedFiName = sender as? String,
    let destVC = segue.destination as? SecondViewController {
  //Your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

View1:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     // create your struct object but in this example you're not passing an array so get rid of the [ ]

     presentNextView(passing: passData)
}

func presentNextView(passing: SecondTable) {
     let next = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "identifierHere") as! View2
     next.fiDetails = passing
     self.present(next, animated: true) 
}
```

identifierHere is set in your main.storyboard, in View2 (the one you want to present) attribute inspector, under viewControllers class. I usually keep it the same as the ViewController name for simplicity but string must match perfectly or you will get a crash.

In View2 you simply need to declare your variables like this:

```
var fiDetails = SecondTable()
```

Do it at the start of the view controller class, not inside the viewDidLoad

I know it's not a segue but I find it a lot more convenient as you also don't need to make any connections in your storyboards, next view gets presented from the function rather then a segue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass the `PassData` struct to the second view controller, pass it as `sender` parameter in `performSegue...`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let fetchedItem = self.fetchedFiName[indexPath.row]
    let selectedFiName = fetchedItem.fiName
    let selectedOneYear = fetchedItem.oneYear
    let selectedTwoYear = fetchedItem.twoYear
    let selectedThreeYear = fetchedItem.threeYear
    let selectedFourYear = fetchedItem.fourYear
    let selectedFiveYear = fetchedItem.fiveYear

    passData = [SecondTable(passedFIName: selectedFiName, passedOneYear: selectedOneYear, passedTwoYear: selectedTwoYear, passedThreeYear: selectedThreeYear, passedFourYear: selectedFourYear, passedFiveYear: selectedFiveYear)]

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController", sender: passData)
}
```

In the destination view controller create a property `fiDetails` rather than a local variable. Then assign the text to the text property of the label.

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var fiName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var sometext: UILabel!

    var fiDetails = SecondTable()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        fiName.text = fiDetails.passedFIName
        sometext.text = "Some Text"
```

In the source view controller in `prepare(for` get the struct from the `sender` parameter and assign it to the `fiDetails` property:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "SecondViewController" {        
        let destVC = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
        let fiDetails = sender as! SecondTable
        destVC.fiDetails = fiDetails
    }
}
```